# cv2.imshow() giving a random error after being called several times

Tags: python, spyder, opencv, assertion

I use cv2 at my laboratory, where I have to show several greyscale images full screen on a display, and then measure some properties on a laser beam that gets affected by that display. The image is an array the size of the correspondent display, with values ranging from 0 to 255. I do it like this:

```
screen_id_main = 0
screen_main = screeninfo.get_monitors()[screen_id_main]
main_name='main_screen'
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.namedWindow(main_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.moveWindow(main_name, screen_main.x - 1, screen_main.y - 1)
cv2.setWindowProperty(main_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow(main_name, mask/256)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

After a certain number of measurements, the program suddenly stops working and drops this error:

```
OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:548: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total() == 0 || data != NULL in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'
```

Which is weird, because it works just fine until then, and there is no change in the "mask" from the last time it works to the next time. After this error, when I run the line:

```
cv2.imshow(main_name, mask/256)
```

The same error drops again. Changing the "mask" or other parameters does not fix the problem. It only stops happening when I restart the terminal.
What is happening here? Is there any way to fix it?
(The environment I use is Spyder)

Thank you!

Comment: your mask is empty

Comment: Hi, the mask is not empty. I have tried changing it and it does not fix the problem